# How to name a source file to show that it is a form

Tags: .net, naming

What is the recommended way to name a source file to show that it is a form as opposed to code only? Visual Basic used to give forms a .frm extension and for code it was .bas, but now it is .vb (or .cs in C#) for everything.

Comment: Not sure if the is a recommendation for that but you can add a prefix like 'frm' to the name or rely on the icon in the solution explorer to see the difference between other files. Does it matter anyway? In the end it is just another class.

Comment: [Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces) says tha we should not add a prefix to class names. I did not see an answer to my question in there. Maybe, like you, they think that it does not matter. The icons are different, but I prefer to read text.